# How to apply CSS to tooltips in Tabulator

Tags: html, css, tabulator

I want my Tabulator table to have CSS applied to the tooltips that appear when hovering over cells. Tabulator adds a `title` tag whenever the user sets `tooltips:true`. However, applying CSS inline is challenging. I did:

```css
div[title]:hover:after {
    content:attr(title) ;
    width: 300px ;
    background-color: black ;
    color: #fff ;
    text-align: center ;
    border-radius: 6px ;
    padding: 5px 0 ;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    z-index: 1 ;
}
```

I haven't worked out positioning or finalized my styles yet. You can see from the below image what happens when I hover over the top left cell.

[image]

I get two tooltips- the default and my custom one. In addition, the custom tooltip stops at the cell edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabulator uses the HTML ***title*** attribute to display tooltips, so the styling is down to the browser and is not user customizable.

If you want a custom tooltip then i would suggest using a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format#format-custom) to add a 3rd party tooltip generation plugin.